# Titanium display image on xml from local

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I was storing the full path of an image & retrieved it below, I want to know why does this image file path,doesn't display in imageview on xml?
    file://localhost/Users/rhez/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/76BDE731-037A-43F8-997B-DAFCA6E0D509/Documents/1372402304473-ea.jpg

```
<TableView dataCollection="photos">
<TableViewRow id="row" dataId="" model="{id}">
<View id="holderview">
<ImageView id="imageview" url="{path}"></ImageView>
</View>
</TableViewRow>
</TableView>
```

However as I view in the finder where the application project documents is located the image is stored in there.Is there something wrong on displaying/retrieving on my xml? Thanks for all your courage in helping.

Comment: please incldue the .tss file are you setting height and width

Comment: Hi,  I figured it out that in my tss file I set the image height & width is smaller than the actual dimensions of the image so I changed it prior to the image dimensions I uploaded. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the [`image`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ImageView-property-image) property, not url, url is deprecated.

```
<TableView dataCollection="photos">
    <TableViewRow id="row" dataId="" model="{id}">
        <View id="holderview">
            <ImageView id="imageview" image="{path}"></ImageView>
        </View>
    </TableViewRow>
</TableView>
```